# Script in /etc/network/if-up.d not executing when eth1 is on

Tags: networking, scripts, ifconfig

I have a script in /etc/network/if-up.d . My intention is that script will execute automatically whenever my eth1 interface is up. But it is not happening. The script also have 755 permission level. Do i need to put the script in a different directory?

Comment: How did you configure the interface? via `network-manager` or via `ifupdown` ?

Comment: What did u mean by configure?

Comment: I meant have you configured the interface by `network-manager` (file/GUI) or via the `/etc/network/interfaces` file or simply by `ifconfig` command..

Comment: I never configured it. It is done automatically. Actually I am running ubuntu using a VMware virtual machine. So the vmware will do configuration for me.

Comment: That means you are using DHCP and `network-manager` is taking care of the networking..you are on a desktop, right? whats the output of `grep -B1 '^managed' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` ?

Comment: the output of the your command is `[ifupdown] managed=false`. What does that means?

Comment: That means `network-manager` will not manage `ifuodown` scripts..whats the output of `grep '^plugins' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` ?

Comment: The output is `plugins=ifupdown,keyfile`.

Comment: Change the `managed=false` to `managed=true` after the line `[ifupdown]` ..restart the NetworkManager `sudo service network-manager restart` ..then check......

Comment: I have the same problems here. That is a nice hint. I set `managed` to `true` and restarted. But doesn't work. I even add a simple `touch` command direct after the Shebang in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown` (that script should call `run-parts` on `/etc/network/if-up.d`). And it looks like that his script is never called.

Comment: Do not forget to put interpreter description (#!/bin/sh ) as the first line of your script !!!

Comment: I have the same issue as stated in the original question.  I got the same outputs from the grep searches requested by @heemayl .  Even though I changed managed=false to managed=true and restarted the NetworkManager it still does not run.